# Run multiple cron groups but not all in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-cron, group, command, schedule

I wanted to run the following way.

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="test_group1","test_group2","test_group3"
```

OR

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="test_group1,test_group2,test_group3"
```

What is the valid command for this?
If not possible though command, what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such way as asked in question.
I got the alternate way.

Run the CRON comman without mentioning group flag. It will execute all CRON jobs having any group. The best way to avoid any group is to remove the CRON job having that group. We can keep the CRON code as backup. But just comment out code schedule inside etc/crontab.xml

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```